# Trouble checking if props is undefined

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, undefined

So I have a page in my project that has a get and then it passes the response to a const, as below.

```
const [reference, setReference] = useState([])   
 
useEffect(() => {
            api.get(`/${props.route.params.index}`).then( response => {
                setReference(response.data)
                setLegendaryAction(response.data.legendary_actions)
            }).catch( error => 
                console.log(error) 
            )
        }, [])
```

Then I pass diferent parts of the reference to multiple instances of the same component.
As the following example, there is reference.action and reference.reaction. I will always have an action, but sometimes Reaction will be undefined, so I'm cheking if it's true before I render my component.

```
                <ReferenceDetails 
                    detailTitle="Actions" 
                    details={reference.actions}
                />
                {reference.reactions && 
                    <ReferenceDetails 
                         detailTitle="Reactions" 
                         details={reference.reactions}
                    />
                }
```

But it gives me this error:

> Error: Text strings must be rendered within a  component.

But when I do console.log(reference.reactions) it returns undefined.
Could someone shed some light here please?

Comment: If you comment out the `reactions` part, the error is gone?

Comment: No, it still happens. If I comment the details then it's gone

Comment: Can you please add the code of `ReferenceDetails` component?

Answer (score 0):

console.log(reference.reactions) should initially give undefined and then give expected value. Did you try console.log(reference?.reactions) ?
Or, console.log(reference && reference.reactions)

Comment: So, there are cases that it gives the expected value, but as I said, some times it won't have a value, so it just gives me undefined